# SQL: Create a new id column that changes based on the values of other three columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns named `cid`, `orderdate`, and `priororderdate` among others.

Here is how the table looks:

```
cid  orderdate            priororderdate              position 
12   NULL                  NULL                           1
12   NULL                  NULL                           2
12   NULL                  NULL                           3
12   2014-08-08 23:25      NULL                           1
12   2014-08-08 23:25      NULL                           2
12   2014-08-08 23:25      NULL                           3
12   2014-08-08 23:25      NULL                           4
12   2014-09-06 17:19      2014-08-08 23:25               1
12   2014-09-06 17:19      2014-08-08 23:25               2
12   2014-09-06 17:19      2014-08-08 23:25               3
13   NULL                  NULL                           1
13   NULL                  NULL                           2
13   NULL                  NULL                           3
```

The combination of the columns `cid`, `orderdatetime`, and `priororderdatetime` defines a unique `fpid` (a new column I want to create). Hence, the final result would be:

```
cid  orderdate            priororderdate              position       fpid
12   NULL                  NULL                           1            1
12   NULL                  NULL                           2            1
12   NULL                  NULL                           3            1
12   2014-08-08 23:25      NULL                           1            2
12   2014-08-08 23:25      NULL                           2            2
12   2014-08-08 23:25      NULL                           3            2
12   2014-08-08 23:25      NULL                           4            2
12   2014-09-06 17:19      2014-08-08 23:25               1            3
12   2014-09-06 17:19      2014-08-08 23:25               2            3
12   2014-09-06 17:19      2014-08-08 23:25               3            3
13   NULL                  NULL                           1            4
13   NULL                  NULL                           2            4
13   NULL                  NULL                           3            4
```

How can I create the `fpid` column?

Comment: The data you show, shows fpid not unique. You can calculate the value using a trigger or in your program code and enforce uniqueness on db level using a unique index.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135230) since you can distinguish all rows where the first three columns are the same using `GROUP BY`. What are you going to use `fpid` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `dense_rank()` in a `select` query:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by cid, orderdate, priororderdate) as fpid
from table t;
```

If you have the column `fpid` already in the table and want to update it:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by cid, orderdate, priororderdate) as new_fpid
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set fpid = new_fpid;
```

(If you want to add it, you can use an `alter table` statement.)

Comment: Very clean and efficient solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit confusion that you say that fpid is unique, but looking at your desired output, it looks like you want to use ROW_NUMBER().

```
UPDATE tab2 t SET fpid =
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY cid)
FROM tab2
GROUP BY cid, orderdate, priororderdate
WHERE t.cid = cid
AND t.orderdate = orderdate
AND t.priororderdate = priororderdate)
```

Comment: This seems correct but for some reason I couldn't make it work. Thank you for posting your reply.